# How to filter records that match only the record specified

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to query sql database using

```
"SELECT content From hapt WHERE osis like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

the `osis` contains records like `Gen.1, Gen.2, Gen.11, Gen.21, etc`.
To search where it is `Gen.1`, it also filters through `Gen.1, Gen.11, Gen.12, etc`.
What syntax can i used to bring me only `Gen.1` record?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation for adding values to a query. Use parameterized queries. And normalize your schema, read: ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Apart from anything else, you should learn to use parameters with ADO.NET because the code you have could potentially be used by a malicious user to delete your whole database.

Comment: I’m totally agree with answers and comments related to your question about use of "SqlParameter" and avoiding use of "LIKE" in a sql as is heavy, saying that, this is one of alternatives you can use:
"SELECT content From hapt WHERE LEFT(osis, 5) = 'Gen.1'"

Answer (score 1):

This question shows that you haven't really bothered doing any basic research into SQL. If you had then you'd know what the `LIKE` operator does and why using it here is wrong. If you want to match values that are equal to a specific value rather than like a specific value then you should obviously be using the `=` operator rather than the `LIKE` operator. Hopefully it is also obvious that you don't use wildcards with the `=` operator.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, it never came to my mind. I do use `=` very well. I'm indeed very sorry.. too much things jam packed on the head